# VSCode C# Intellisense not displaying correct autocompletions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

i'm using VSCode for a quick and Lite programming, but Intellisense does not work giving autocompletion out of the box, instead it only shows options of word that are frequently used or common snippets in code.

Comment: do you have correct extensions installed?

Comment: yes i have correct extensions installed

Comment: sometimes you need to type more than 2 characters, type the full prefix and see if it shows

Comment: no, when the extensions run on top appear the class and method that i am typping in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, kinda. The C# extension can fail to initialize due to low performance, the Intellisense is magically fixed when you restart the Omnisharp server